# Experimental Support For Decorators warning 1 file

Tags: angular, typescript

I can't seem to understand what the issues is, but only 1 file is reporting the Experimental Support For Decorators is Subject to Change in a Future Release warning. I have been unable to find any SO threads that mentions anything other than all files reporting this and editing the tsconfig file.

Anything I could be missing? I've created other files with decorators and not getting this error.

The file in question looks like this:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

import { Client } from '../models/client.model';

import { ClientEditorComponent } from './client-editor.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-edit-client-dialog',
    templateUrl: 'edit-client-dialog.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['edit-client-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class EditClientDialogComponent
{
    @ViewChild(ClientEditorComponent)
    editClient: ClientEditorComponent;

    get clientName(): any {        
        return this.data.client ? { name: this.data.client.client_Name } : null;
    }

    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditClientDialogComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: { client: Client }
    ) {
        console.log(this.data.client);
        console.log(this.data.client.client_Name);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.data.client);
        this.editClient.clientSaved$.subscribe(client => this.dialogRef.close(client));
    }

    cancel(): void {
        console.log(this.data.client);
        this.dialogRef.close(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for fun, have you tried restarting your IDE?  Or are you getting this on the command line.  Have you verified you only have one tsconfig.json?

Comment: I'm using VS2017 and have restarted it numerous times trying to fix the problem. I do only have 1 tsconfig. It's very odd, as it is just this one file that seems to keep the warning no matter what I do.

Comment: Is the file included in the project explicitly? I think Vs creates some virtual project for extrenal files... but I am not sure.